# Sort the header using fnstandingredraw in datatable

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm using jquery datatable version 1.9.4 i need to sort the column header per page. i have tried fnstandingredraw function.But i didn't work.

Here is my code.

```
function ModalFormSuccess() {
    var LocSearch = document.getElementById("LocSearch").value; 
    var table=$('#dacrudtable').dataTable({
         "sDom": "<'row'<'col-sm-6'T><'col-sm-6'f>r>t<'row'<'col-sm-6'i><'col-sm-6'p>>",
         "sAjaxSource": "ajax.php",
         "fnServerParams": function(aoData) {
             aoData.push({
                 "name": "cSearch",
                 "value": LocSearch
             });
        },
         "bServerSide": true,
         "bSearchable": false,
         "bAutoWidth": false,
         "bDestroy": true,
         "bStateSave": true
         'iDisplayLength': 500,
         "aoColumns": [{ "mData":"status", "sClass":"center "},
            { "mData":"void_invoice", "sClass":"center "},
            { "mData":"created_date", "sClass":"center" },
            { "mData":"transfer_in_date", "sClass":"center" },
]
table.fnStandingRedraw();
}
```

I followed the procedure from http://www.craiglotter.co.za/2012/05/28/how-to-refresh-a-datatable-without-losing-your-current-page-or-ordering/
What am i missing here?Can anyone help?

Comment: Add  `"bSortable": true` in your  `"aoColumns"`

Comment: Move `table.fnStandingRedraw();` so it's outside of the datatable initialisation code

Comment: @SanyamiVaidya : I added "bSortable" : true after "bStateSave" : true .But it again jumps to beginning of the page

Comment: Try this,  "aoColumns": [{ "mData":"status", "sClass":"center ","bSortable": true},
            { "mData":"void_invoice", "sClass":"center ","bSortable": true},
            { "mData":"created_date", "sClass":"center","bSortable": true },
            { "mData":"transfer_in_date", "sClass":"center" ,"bSortable": true},
]